# python ADO DB API gives MS SQL cursor engine out of memory error. What is an alternative to python ado db api?

Tags: python, pyodbc, pymssql, adodbapi

I am currently using python with adodb api for MS Sql database connection. This is working very well for smaller databases. But for large databases when the query is returning huge data, I get MS Sql cursor out of memory error. This works fine with Server side cursor. But then it consumes lot of memory on my server.

**Question 1**: How can I continue to use client side cursor? Can reading data in chunks be an option?

**Question 2**: Is there any alternative to python ado db API?

I searched for other options to connect to MS Sql. Found this link about comparison  - [pymssql versus pyodbc versus adodbapi versus...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812631/pymssql-versus-pyodbc-versus-adodbapi-versus). This looks old information. I have started my own investigation with pyodbc and pymssql.

Can anybody recommend which is better out of these?

Comment: Of the three connection options you mentioned, pyodbc is the one that is [officially supported by Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/12/09/sql-server-python-whats-new/).

Comment: Thanks Gord for information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Gord, I tested my code with pyodbc and its working 3 times faster than adodb api.